# Laravel multiple upload with image preview then crop

Tags: jquery, laravel-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, crop, jquery-file-upload

I'm trying to build a form using laravel 4 were i upload multiple images then preview them, after that i need to let the user crop the image then save both file (original and cropped).

any idea on how to approach this?

Comment: Did you try to use the [tag:jquery-file-upload] widget?

Comment: yes, but i did know how to add the preview then crop functionality to it. can you help in that?

Comment: You should read [this page](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options), every options are documented.

Comment: i read it, but it's not working with me

Comment: How is it not working for you? If you want help then you need to describe a specific problem and show us what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at doing something very similar in the near future.

My planned approach is to use [Jquery file upload for Laravel](https://github.com/zimt28/laravel-jquery-file-upload) as a starting point and then should I run into any issues I cant solve come back here with a **specific question and a code example**.

Please note the linked code is not built for laravel 4.1 so you may run into some specific issues very quickly.

If you search [packagist](https://packagist.org/) you will also find a number of image manipulation libs including some built specifically for laravel 4

Comment: So there is no file upload image for laravel 4.1 ? i mean like this?